# VB How to pass a multidimensional array to and from an Active X control

Tags: arrays, vb.net, activex

I have a multi-dimensional array named OPIMG(2000,2000,10)as long, this contains sets of image data (16bit greyscale images as data for use within the user control) which I create on the main form.  I need to be able to access this data from within the active X but cannot get the array into the control.

I tried creating a new array within the control and copying the data over value by value, but this took too much time, so i need to find a way of being able to directly access the common array from the user control.

Comment: Did you write the ActiveX control?  It sounds like you have the source code... if yes, what language is the ActiveX control written in?

Comment: That sounds a lot of memory to pass back and forth. If you can rewrite your code to pass an iterator like IEnumVARIANT the memory footprint could be a lot smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sheng Ziang thats its a lot of memory to pass over as it works out to

```
2000 x 2000 x 10 = 40,000,000 
Approximately 40Mb
```

Yet still, to answer your question, I have pasted the code for the page and for the user control.

```
PAGE CODE

<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Register Src="~/MyUserControl.ascx" TagName="MyUserCtrlItem" TagPrefix="UC1" %>
<script runat="server">

Private _MyArray(,,) As Long
'
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
'
Dim X As Integer
Dim Y As Integer
Dim Z As Integer
Dim Number As Long
  '
  ' Populate array with test data
  ReDim _MyArray(2000, 2000, 10)
  For Z = 0 To 9
    For Y = 0 To 199
      For X = 0 To 199
        Number = Number + 1
        _MyArray(X, Y, Z) = Number
      Next
    Next
  Next
  MyUserCtrlItem1.MyCtrlArray = _MyArray
  '
End Sub
'
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <UC1:MyUserCtrlItem ID="MyUserCtrlItem1" runat="server" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code for the user control

```
USER CONTROL

<%@ Control Language="VB" ClassName="MyUserControl" %>

<script runat="server">

Private _MyCtrlArray(,,) As Long

Property MyCtrlArray As Array
  Get
    Return _MyCtrlArray
  End Get
  Set(value As Array)
    _MyCtrlArray = value
  End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
  If TextBox1.Text <> "" Then
    If TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
      If TextBox3.Text <> "" Then
        Label1.Text = _MyCtrlArray(CInt(TextBox1.Text), CInt(TextBox2.Text), CInt(TextBox3.Text))
      Else
        Label1.Text = "Z value missing/invalid!"
      End If
    Else
      Label1.Text = "Y value missing/invalid!"
    End If
  Else
    Label1.Text = "X value missing/invalid!"
  End If
  TextBox1.Text = ""
  TextBox2.Text = ""
  TextBox3.Text = ""
End Sub

</script>

<!-- HTML -->
X Value: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
Y Value: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
Z Value: <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br /><br />
Data: <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

In the sample code, you enter a value for X Y and Z and it will return the VALUE held in that element of NUMBER (which I just incremented in the page load event)

Comment: Many thanks guys, this seems to work fine. But I hadnt thought of the memory usage. Just as an afterthought I was thinking would it be faster and more efficient to locate the memory start-end address for the array and send that information to the active X control..  Both have been written in VB by myself so I can manipulate the data however I want. But then Im not sure how to point the array to that address.  Think im in over my head here, but it needs doing